# Access GPIO on beaglebone as non root user?

Tags: python, linux, beagleboneblack, beagleboard, udev

I asked all around and any udev rules i tried simply didn't work.

What i need is to be able to access gpio pins as some other use than root.

For example, executing python script from Adafruit which is supposed to read temperature from sensor, and i got this:

```
$ python Adafruit_Python_DHT/examples/simpletest.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Adafruit_Python_DHT/examples/simpletest.py", line 39, in <module>
    humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, pin)
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_DHT/common.py", line 90, in read_retry
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_DHT/common.py", line 77, in read
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_DHT/Beaglebone_Black.py", line 213, in read
RuntimeError: Error accessing GPIO. Make sure program is run as root with sudo!
```

I tried many different tips to resolve this but it works only if i use it as root
I tried this: https://gist.github.com/metasoarous/a7308779837f9dcba662 and this https://github.com/metasoarous/strange-coop/tree/master/etc

And some other udev/rules.d but nothing worked so far...

Any idea how to change this?

Comment: Would it be acceptable to run sudo from within your script, probably from a no-password sudo user?  It's not an elegant solution but maybe you could just do that from the subprocess module.

Comment: AH, at the end i decided to go with root environment... BB really needs nice interface/application to manage pins.. as rpi already have

Answer (score 0):

I tried below instructions based on [this](https://github.com/adafruit/adafruit-beaglebone-io-python/issues/137) and worked:

1. run  `nano /etc/udev/rules.d/80-gpio-permissions.rules`
2. write

   ```
   KERNEL=="gpio*", SUBSYSTEM=="gpio", ACTION=="add", PROGRAM="/usr/local/bin/udev-gpio-permissions.sh"
   ```
3. run  `nano /usr/local/bin/udev-gpio-permissions.sh`
4. copy

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   # Result: chown debian:root /sys/class/gpio

   chown -R debian:root /sys/devices/gpio
   chown -R debian:root /sys/class/gpio
   chown -R debian:root /sys/devices/platform/ocp
   chown -R debian:root /sys/class/pwm

   #GPIO ( active_low device direction edge power subsystem uevent value )
   find /sys/class/gpio -type d -exec chmod 2770 {} \;
   find /sys/class/gpio -name "direction" -exec chmod 0660 {} \;
   find /sys/class/gpio -name "edge" -exec chmod 0660 {} \;
   find /sys/class/gpio -name "value" -exec chmod 0660 {} \;
   find /sys/class/gpio -name "active_low" -exec chmod 0660 {} \;
   find /sys/class/gpio -name "device" -exec chmod 0660 {} \;
   find /sys/class/gpio -name "power" -exec chmod 0660 {} \;
   find /sys/class/gpio -name "subsystem" -exec chmod 0660 {} \;

   chmod 0220 /sys/class/gpio/export
   chmod 0220 /sys/class/gpio/unexport

   find /sys/class/gpio -name "uevent" -exec chmod 0660 {} \;
   find /sys/class/gpio -name "autosuspend_delay_ms" -exec chmod 0660 {} \;
   find /sys/class/gpio -name "control" -exec chmod 0660 {} \;
   ```
5. run 
   `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/udev-gpio-permissions.sh`
6. run 
   `udevadm control --reload-rules`
7. reboot